# Android app to show bandwith usage(speed) of apps

Tags: android, networking, network-monitor, internet

I am looking for an app like the android version of **Netlimiter** for Windows.
I have tried some apps which promised to do the above but all they did is just show overall data usage. i.e

App ABCD this week= 1.0GB data
App ETC this month = 2.5GB data

The app I am looking for should show the current bandwith usage in terms of speed usage i.e

App ABCD is using 50 *KB/s*
App ETC is using 100 *KB/s*

So I am looking for *live speed* and not statistics. Unfortunately, my tablet can't run [NetLive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.richardlucasapps.netlive), which otherwise looks fitting.